# If $a + b = \frac{1}{4}$, what is $a^3 + b^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just want to know how to solve this problem.

If $a + b = \dfrac{1}{4}$, what is $a^3 + b^3$ equals to?

---

My work - but still doesn't give me an answer.

$a^2 + b^2 = (a + b)^2 - 2ab = \dfrac{1}{16} - 2ab$

$a^3 + b^3 = (a + b)^3 - 3ab(a + b) = \dfrac{1}{64} - \dfrac{3ab}{4}$.

How can I get the value for $ab$ here?

Comment: The title question has no unique answer. Take $a=0$, $b=1/4$, or $a=b=1/8$.

Comment: you have insufficient information to determine $a^3+b^3$.

Comment: Note $b=\frac14-a$ so the most you can do is $$a^3+b^3=a^3+\left(\frac14-a\right)^3=a^3+\frac1{64}-\frac3{16}a+\frac34a^2-a^3=\frac1{64}(48a^2-12a+1)$$ which has no real roots.

Comment: Do you know what $a-b$ is?

Answer (score 5):

The value of $y = a^3+b^3$ contains a family of solutions (like a curve). You cannot establish a value for $y$ unless something else is specified.

For example besides $a+b = \tfrac{1}{4}$, let us use some artbitrary value $a-b = \lambda$. The solve for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $\lambda$ and put them into $y$

$$ y = \left( \frac{1+4 \lambda}{8} \right)^3 + \left( \frac{1-4 \lambda}{8} \right)^3=\frac{1}{256} + \frac{3 \lambda^2}{16} = \frac{1}{256} + \frac{3 (a-b)^2}{16}$$

<sub>so the *minimum* value of y exists when a=b, and thus λ=0.</sub>

Comment: A quick calculation I did just now (paper and pen entirely, so might have arithmetic errors) leads to $a^3 + b^3 = a^3 + (\frac{1}{4} - a)^3 = \frac{3}{4}a^2 - \frac{3}{16}a + \frac{1}{64},$ which has a minimum at $a = \frac{1}{8}$ (complete the square, use calculus, or use the "x = b/2a formula"), whose corresponding minimum value is $\frac{1}{256},$ so since the graph is a parabola that opens upward, we know that any real number greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{256}$ can be the value of $a^3 + b^3,$ and no real number less than $\frac{1}{256}$ can be the value of $a^3 + b^3.$

Comment: I take it back. The minimum $a^3+b^3$ is $1/256$. I made a typo and the result has $\lambda^2$ and not $\lambda^3$ as I originally posted. You see $a=1/8$ means also that $b=1/8$ and so $y=1/256$ as stated above.